# Data type mismatch error in my windows form application

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have a problem when I click the add button. And this problem is data type mismatch error. 
This is for my homework. I have some data for this homework.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJZw3.jpg)

My access database is this. I thought this problem occurred from date/time but i considered that is not from date/time.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd =new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Sayfa1(S_adı, Police1, Kayit_Turu, TC1_veya_Vergi_No1, M_adı, Police1_No1, Plaka1, Belge1_Seri1, B_tarihi, Bas_tarihi, N_fiyat, B_fiyat, Telefon1_No1) values(@SirketAdi, @Police, @KayıtTuru, @TCVergiNo, @MusteriAdı, @PoliceNosu, @Plaka, @BelgeSeri, @BitisTarihi, @BaslangicTarihi, @NetFiyat, @BrutFiyat, @TelefonNosu)",con) ;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SirketAdi", s_adı.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Police", p_adı.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KayıtTuru", k_adı);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCVergiNo", v_nosu.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MusteriAdı", m_adı.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PoliceNosu", p_nosu.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plaka", p_sı.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BelgeSeri", b_serisi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BitisTarihi", dateTimePicker3.Value.ToShortDateString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaslangicTarihi", dateTimePicker4.Value.ToShortDateString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetFiyat", n_fiyat.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrutFiyat", brut.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelefonNosu", komisyon.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            griddoldur();
        }
```

`System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException`

Comment: In Sql Insert Statement - Verify All Columns (DataType) matches with values passing from textboxes .

Comment: why no `.Text` for @KayitTuru

Comment: In Sql Insert Statement - Verify All Columns (DataType) matches with values passing from textboxes .         I did that. The data is coming to textboxes from datagridview, so there is no problem there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not everything in this world is *text*, indeed the dates probably are not. So try:

```
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BitisTarihi", dateTimePicker3.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaslangicTarihi", dateTimePicker4.Value);
```

Comment: Then replace `Parameters.AddWithValue` with `Parameters.Add` which allows you to specify the data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            con.Open();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd =new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Sayfa1(S_adi,Police1,Kayit_Turu,TC1_veya_Vergi_No1,M_adi,Police1_No1,Plaka1,Belge1_Seri1,B_tarihi,Bas_tarihi,N_fiyat,B_fiyat,Telefon1_No1) values (@SirketAdi, @Police, @KayıtTuru, @TCVergiNo, @MusteriAdı, @PoliceNosu, @Plaka, @BelgeSeri, @BitisTarihi, @BaslangicTarihi, @NetFiyat, @BrutFiyat, @TelefonNosu)",con) ;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SirketAdi", s_adi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Police", p_adi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KayıtTuru", k_adi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCVergiNo", v_nosu.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MusteriAdı", m_adi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PoliceNosu", p_nosu.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Plaka", p_si.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BelgeSeri", b_serisi.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BitisTarihi", dateTimePicker3.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaslangicTarihi", dateTimePicker4.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetFiyat", n_fiyat.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BrutFiyat", brut.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelefonNosu", komisyon.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            griddoldur();
        }
```

Now, I made like this codes. I think the problem may be due to the database. But I didn't understand.